# lodash calculate difference between array elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

In javascript using lodash, I need a way to calculate the difference between array elements, for instance:

With an array of
`[0,4,3,9,10]`
I need to get the difference between each element.
output should be
`[4,-1,6,1]`

How would I do this using lodash?

In ruby it looks something like this:
`ary.each_cons(2).map { |a,b| b-a }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution is with using **[_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map)**:

```js
var arr = [0,4,3,9,10];

var result = _.map(arr, function(e, i) {
  return arr[i+1] - e;
});

result.pop();

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.9.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something do something like this:

```
var arr = [0, 4, 3, 9, 10];
var res = [];
_.reduce(_.rest(arr), function (prev, next) {
  res.push(next - prev);
  return next;
}, arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more idiomatic lodash solution:

```
_.zipWith(arr.slice(1), arr.slice(0, -1), _.subtract)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [_.reduce](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce):

```js
(function () {
    var nums = [0,4,3,9,10];
    var diffs = _.reduce(nums, function(result, value, index, collection) {
        if (index === 0) return result;
        result[index] = value - collection[index - 1];
        return result;
    }, []).slice(1);
    
    $('.output').text(JSON.stringify(diffs));
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.9.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div class=output></div>
```